# When is it appropriate to use singleton instance of a database?

Tags: android, singleton, database-connection, sqlite

I'm quite new to android and I'm trying to make an application that logs people's communication patterns on their smartphone and presents it to them in an interesting way.

Right now I have a service running in the background that listens for outgoing calls/texts and incoming calls/texts. I want to put this data into a database and then use data to populate an interface. When ever new data is put into the database I want the interface to reflect that.

My question is then: What would be a good approach for this?

I was told that ways of doing it are to have the database be a **singleton instance** or wrapping the database in a **Content Provider**. Is anyone able to elaborate further on this?

This is my code for my table

```
public class LogTable {

//Database name and Version
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "logs.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


//Database Table
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "logs";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PHONENUMBER = "phonenumber";
public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
public static final String COLUMN_INCOMING = "incoming";
public static final String COLUMN_OUTGOING = "outgoing";


//Preventing someone from accidentally instantiating the class
//Giving it an empty constructor
public LogTable(){}

//Database creation SQL statement
public static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + COLUMN_PHONENUMBER + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT, "
        + COLUMN_DATE + " INTEGER, "
        + COLUMN_INCOMING + " INTEGER, "
        + COLUMN_OUTGOING + " INTEGER + );";}
```

And this is the code for my MySQliteHelper

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



//Constructor
public MySQLiteHelper(Context ctx)
{
    super(ctx, LogTable.DATABASE_NAME, null, LogTable.DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
//Method called during creation of the database
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(LogTable.DATABASE_CREATE);
    Log.i("SQL", "Database Created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + LogTable.TABLE_NAME);

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer here for a similar question may help you decide how to handle such a scenario.

[Easy database access methods in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234451/easy-database-access-methods-in-android/17234910#17234910)

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to you is create a async task queue for database operations so you wont get errors and do db operations on background and create singleton of this queue

advantage of this approach is there wont be need for synchronous function

for doing this you should implement an extension of async task

operations propose is it send message to queue so queue can execute new operation
you can look for my gist if you want

https://gist.github.com/TalhaAkkas/6697962