# Multiple SQLLiteOpenHelpers only the first table is created on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to use the SQLiteOpenHelper to store multiple tables into a db. I came up with this common base class.

```
public abstract class BaseHelper<T> extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "helperdb";

public BaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// TODO: Add Java docs here
public abstract String getTableName();

public abstract String getCreateQuery();

public abstract ContentValues getValues(T item);

public abstract T get(Object... id);

public abstract T create(Cursor cursor);

public abstract int update(T item);

public abstract void delete(T item);

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(getCreateQuery());
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(PlayerHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
            + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
            + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL(getUpdateQuery());
    onCreate(db);
}

public String getUpdateQuery() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ");
    sb.append(getTableName());
    return sb.toString();
}

public List<T> getAll() {
    List<T> itemList = new ArrayList<T>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + getTableName();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            T item = create(cursor);
            itemList.add(item);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return itemList;
}

// Getting contacts Count
public int getCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + getTableName();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

public void add(T item) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(getTableName(), null, getValues(item));
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
}
```

Then I have multiple implementations here is an example of 1.

```
public class TeamHelper extends BaseHelper<Team> {

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "teams";

public TeamHelper(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public String getCreateQuery() {
    StringBuilder creator = new StringBuilder();
    creator.append("CREATE TABLE ").append(getTableName()).append("(");
    for (Team.SQLValues v : Team.SQLValues.values()) {
        creator.append(v.toString()).append(" ")
                .append(Team.SQLValues.getType(v)).append(", ");
    }
    return creator.substring(0, creator.length() - 2) + ")";
}

@Override
public String getTableName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return TABLE_NAME;
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
@Override
public ContentValues getValues(Team item) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    for (Team.SQLValues v : Team.SQLValues.values()) {
        switch (v) {
        case TEAM_ID:
            values.put(v.toString(), Long.toString(item.getTeamId()));
            break;
        case TEAM_NAME:
            values.put(v.toString(), item.getTeamName());
            break;
        case RANK:
            values.put(v.toString(), item.getRank());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return values;
}

@Override
// Getting single contact
public Team get(Object... id) {
    if(id.length != 1){
        return null;
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,
            new String[] { Team.SQLValues.TEAM_ID.toString(),
                    Team.SQLValues.TEAM_NAME.toString(),
                    Team.SQLValues.TOTALPOINTS.toString() },
            Team.SQLValues.TEAM_ID.toString() + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id[0]) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    return create(cursor);
}

public Team create(Cursor cursor) {
    Team contact = new Team();
    contact.setTeamId(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(0)));
    contact.setTeamName(cursor.getString(1));
    contact.setTotalPoints(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
    return contact;
}

// Updating single contact
@Override
public int update(Team contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Team.SQLValues.TEAM_NAME.toString(), contact.getTeamName());
    // values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, Team.SQLValues.TEAM_ID.toString()
            + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getTeamId()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
@Override
public void delete(Team contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, Team.SQLValues.TEAM_ID.toString() + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getTeamId()) });
    db.close();
}



}
```

Then I call these SQLLiteHelpers individually in the activity as so...

```
public static List<Team> getTeams(Context c) {
    TeamHelper db = new TeamHelper(c);
    return db.getAll();
}

public static List<Player> getPlayers(Context x){
    PlayerHelper h = new PlayerHelper(x);
    return h.getAll();
}

public static List<PlayerTeam> getPlayerTeams(Context x){
    PlayerTeamHelper h = new PlayerTeamHelper(x);
    return h.getAll();
}

List<Team> t = LoginTask.getTeams(this);
List<Player> t2 = LoginTask.getPlayers(this);       
List<PlayerTeam> t3 = LoginTask.getPlayerTeams(this);
```

The problem here is the first one works fine, the second and third say there are no tables that match. If I change the order the table that works also changes. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Can you not have more than one helper?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be overcomplicating things. You only need one helper per database not per table.

Using multiple helpers will likely get you running into all sorts of trouble such as database locked exceptions. It would also make performing multi table transactions pretty impossible.

Have a look at this answer I posted previously for an example of an easy and maintainable way of data access.

[Easy database access methods in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234451/easy-database-access-methods-in-android/17234910#17234910)