# Creating single instances of each class in the inheritance hierarchy

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Suppose there are three classes namely **A, B** and **C** such that **B extends A**, **C extends B**.

Requirement is that client code should be able to **call the constructors of each class only once** successfully. Upon trying to **call constructor twice** it should **throw an exception**.

How can I implement this in Java if duplication of code is not permitted in the child classes?

Example :

```
public class A {
    private static A instance;

    public A() {
        if (instance != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        instance = this;
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private static B instance;

    public B() {
        if (instance != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        instance = this;
    }
}

public class C extends B {
    private static C instance;
    public C() {
        if (instance != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        instance = this;
    }

}

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a1 = new A();
        B b1 = new B(); //throwing IllegalArgumentException, it should not throw
    }
}
```

Things I tried.

Maintaining a private static reference of the respective class type which is initially set as null.
In the constructor block I added a null check to assign ***this*** reference to the static reference. Did not work as I could not avoid duplicating code.

Requirement

```
//this should work fine

A a1 = new A();
B b1 = new B();
C c1 = new C();

---------------

//this should throw runtime exception

A a1 = new A();
A a2 = new A();
B b1 = new B();


---------------
//this should throw runtime exception

A a1 = new A();
B b1 = new B();
B b2 = new B();

---------------

//this should throw runtime exception

A a1 = new A();
B b1 = new B();
C c1 = new C();
C c2 = new C();
```

I hope I am clear with the requirements

Comment: write a singleton

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single instance of Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062520/single-instance-of-java-class)

Comment: Hi fantaghirocco, I am aware of Singleton Pattern. But I think the requirement is slightly different

Comment: What do you mean by no duplication of code?

Comment: I should not override any method in child class just to write similar logic.

Comment: @akshay Could you show what you have tried and why you can't use it?

Comment: @hev1 I have edited the question. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

We have established that the subclass implicitly calls the super constructor, which in return throws.

## 1. Singleton / Factory Method solution

What you want to achieve is described as a Singleton design pattern. It conceptually requires a `static` members.
Static fields and/or methods (if you want to use a factory method) are not inherited, so duplication of the code which manipulates the static field is inevitable.

You **should** use the duplicated null-check & store static instance technique, it is widely used and accepted. The amount of code duplication is minimal and you should not be scared of it.

**EDITED** as to implicit super constructor call: You can use a condition (as in `A`) or a factory method (as in `B`).

```
public class A {
    private static A instance;
    
    public A() {
        if (this.getClass() == A.class) {
            if (instance != null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            instance = this;
        }
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private static B instance;

    private B() { }

    public static B getInstance() {
        if (instance != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return instance = new B();
    }
}

public class C extends B {
    private static C instance;
        
    public C() {
        // check if (this.getClass() == B.class) when someone extends C
        if (instance != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        instance = this;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a1 = new A();
    B b1 = B.getInstance();
    C c1 = new C();
}
```

Alternatively, you can declare a `private` constructor and have a `static` Factory Method. If you are in a multi-threaded environment, pay attention to *synchronisation*.

---

## 2. Collecting all instances in the top-most parent

An other obscure solution would be to collect all `Class<>` instances in the top parent and check for duplicity in the constructor. **This is not a <strike>good</strike> conventional solution.** The singelton pattern is usual.

```
public class TopClass {
    private static final Set<Class<? extends TopClass>> instances = new HashSet<>();

    public TopClass() {
        if (instances.contains(this.getClass())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        instances.add(this.getClass());
    }
}

public class SubClass extends TopClass {}
public class AnotherClass extends SubClass {}
```

This way you limit **all** future subclasses to be instantiated only once. It is limiting, but yes - less lines of code.

Comment: Could you please explain why you consider your 2nd solution as "not good"? Because it's exactly what the OP is asking for

Comment: @fps well because singleton pattern is the widely known and accepted solution to this problem AFAIK. So why invent something new, if anyone would know what `getInstance()` does on first glance? So basically the reason is convention, I guess.

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question.
It is throwing exception while creating an instance of B as it was calling no arg constructor of its parent class and finding that its static variable is  not null.

As I said it should let call constructor of B once.

Comment: @Hawk, please take a look at the code I posted in the question. As your answer does not say anything about inheritance hierarchy whereas I had explicitly added in the question.

Comment: @Hawk, I want to create an object using constructor only. Not using the getInstance method.

Comment: Without a factory method you can wrap the constructor in a conditional (as in class A) or use the 2nd method with collecting all Class<> instances. That is the most concise and extensible solution (i.e. it works for any amount of subclasses without _any_ code in the subclass)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can make a Set of already initialized classes and check it every time you construct a new one. It allows create **one** instance of A, **one** instance of B and **one** instance of C.

```
class A {
    private static final Set<Class<? extends A>> calledInitializations = new HashSet<>();

    A() {
        checkForSecondInit(A.class);
    }

    protected void checkForSecondInit(Class<? extends A> clazz) {
        if (isNotInSuperClassOf(clazz)) {
            if (calledInitializations.contains(clazz)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Second init in " + clazz.getName());
            } else {
                calledInitializations.add(clazz);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isNotInSuperClassOf(Class<? extends A> clazz) {
        return getClass() == clazz;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    B() {
        checkForSecondInit(B.class);
    }
}

class C extends B {
    C() {
        checkForSecondInit(C.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create static Set collection and add the classname along with package to set. For new object, it will check if there is a existing class name in the set or not.

For thread safety,set is added in synchronized block.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class A {
    static Set<String> set;
    public A(){
       if(set==null){
           synchronized(set){
              set = new HashSet<>();
           }
        }
        String classWithPackage = getClass().toString().split(" ")[1];
        if(set.contains(classWithPackage)){
            throw new RuntimeException("Only one instance can be created for: "+classWithPackage);
        }else {
            synchronized(set){
                set.add(classWithPackage);
            }
        }
    }
}
class B extends A{
    public B(){
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        A a2 = new B();
        B b1 = new B();
    }
}
```